# hide brightcove video and initiate onClick of <a> link

Tags: jquery, brightcove

I have a brightcove video integration in my site and on mobile I would like to hide the video and then when the user clicks a link, it should open the video and start playing.

HTML

```
<div id="video_player"><!-- brightcove player goes here --></div>
<script>
    BCL.addPlayer('video_player', '2327273222001');<!-- 'id' of target div, Brightcove Asset ID -->
</script>
<a class="test" onClick="" href="#">Test</a>
```

http://machinas.com/wip/hugoboss/brightcove/

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hide the video player with CSS, then when the `test` anchor is clicked, show the video player and initialize it, if it hasn't been shown already.

Assuming that `addPlayer` is synchronous, you can call the `play` method immediately afterwards. If it isn't synchronous, then you will need to pass a callback function to addPlayer which calls the play method.

**CSS**

```
#video_player {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a.test').on('click', function(e) {
    var vidPlayer = $('#video_player');

    if(!vidPlayer.is(':visible')) {
        vidPlayer.show();
        BCL.addPlayer('video_player', '2327273222001');<!-- 'id' of target div, Brightcove Asset ID -->   
        brightcove.play(); //assumes your Brightcove variable is named brightcove
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: thanks, that loads the video but it doesn't start the video. How can I make the video start playing too on click. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `display:none;` to hide your video, according to the Brightcove documentation you should use `left:-9999px;` or any other method except hiding.

Also you can't play the video with JS unless the user clicks the play button first. Then you can play, pause, and change the video pragmatically.